# React Typescript distinguish between different prop types, choosing from one of two types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two Typescript interfaces:

```
type ISecond = {
    timeType: string
    secondTime: number
}

type IDay = {
    timeType: string
    startTime: number
    endTime: number
}
```

With my react function props types,

```
...
const CountDown: React.FC<Iprops> = (params: Iprops) => {
    ...
}
...
```

How can I make it only choose from one of these two? If my props has `secondTime`, it cannot have props `startTime` and `endTime`.

I'm using `type Iprops = ISecond | IDay`, but cannot limit it only choose from one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to handle it.

**The simplest way**

Just add one sharable property. For example: `type`

```js
type ISecond = {
  type: 'second',
  timeType: string
  secondTime: number
}

type IDay = {
  type: 'day',
  timeType: string
  startTime: number
  endTime: number
}

type IProps = ISecond | IDay;


const Foo = (prop: IProps) => {
  if (prop.type === 'day') {
    const x = prop; // IDay
  }
  if (prop.type === 'second') {
    const x = prop; // ISecond
  }
}
```

Or you can go by a bit longer way, but I believe more safer. You can add typeguards and leave your types as is:

```js
  type Base = {
    timeType: string
  }

  type ISecond = Base & {
    secondTime: number
  }

  type IDay = Base & {
    startTime: number
    endTime: number
  }

  type IProps = ISecond | IDay;

  const hasProperty = <T extends object>(obj: T, prop: string) =>
    Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

  const isSecond = (obj: IProps):obj is ISecond => hasProperty(obj, 'secondTime')


  const Foo = (prop: IProps) => {
    if (isSecond(prop)) {
      const x = prop; // ISecond
    } else {
      const x = prop; // IDay
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICSBlWBjA9gOwCbwLzwDeo88UcAXPAOQDO62ONANKeQJYC2sAKjLGp1wAJw5YA5uwaZcvboPhYArlwBGsEaAC%20oCAKQARAIaQCxdhUU0cp1pYX8q8YWMnTwxkeHk9qK9U12WDkFf1UNLRBdMBArJAAFEQxoOnMURlx4AB8jUwBuPVjZYXgAMQwMcwAKaGToakQklLoASgIAPgsQMg4AM3ha%20oA6ePxx2ltIGnaSHrJ4EvB4AA9zOpT8%20AB6bbzIdhjegaGU0YNxwnpM5ln2MiXV9fqt3aRUWRxDnSLQOcsDAAhYwMcxzBacHhORSucRSeYxAFwd43czA0EAMm6EJkTF8igCkW%20sTI8UQJjMhHRCCx4IWwi8PjCSgiQXmZBCOHx4UCUTIiPmZOaqXSHyYOX2hRJi2wpQAFiDhZooOYADy8eCwFbgTlpDBqABW6HAHWq%20oN1F4LHgGwaLlEcPa%20A693gAHlDcbhgq6G6AO5YJXeSDDNDGAA24bNhutttaUvYjw4dDFWUI0YtiXqbUo5vgyZRn068B9QagGet10%20%20Jmv3mjwqVXTtsawraxbpx0GydTOFO0Fad3ZC0ea0Itteewyn1d2k14dBnZHsuWY5tLx2U4ps%20JOiAA)

More information about using union with react components you can find in my article [here](https://catchts.com/unions#safe_union)

Comment: Discriminated Union type is the right answer. TS will be able to infer the correct type if you switch on the discriminated field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to distinguish the different types of props that you are using which can be achieved using the `in` operator. As the `IDay` interface contains the property `endTime` and `ISecond` does not you can use it to differentiate the two(you can also use `startTime` here as well).

```
const CountDown: React.FC<Iprops> = (params: Iprops) => {
   'endTime' in params ? (
    // Logic for using IDay goes here 
  ) : (
    // Logic for using ISecond goes here 
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because this control flow makes the assumption that the interface members will never change. If you added or removed endtime from either interface this whole thing would break.

Comment: That is true `captain-yossarian` answer would be a better fit in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Use function overloading

```
function CountDown (params: ISecond);
function CountDown (params: IDay) {
    ...
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature).