# Switching between two different prop types in one React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TL;DR: [Here's the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwDkUqDLwDcAKFCRYiQTAAiAeQCyHLj34yAtABNuI0eIB2zKGXQsEuUXGsdgSADZaAXHEIwowAwHMxNuBDAkKCZoFzcPb18bADcUe3wkFxQDAE8xVkNjUzRzAHFLPzRuACNPEKgXXmStXjgAHz5oPT8ofHskQhcACgsGhFyASgBtAF10zKDsvIBJAGECm1b2zrge3Ln6xE2qgxrtpuGx0QyYFMDEXIBBVLgAXgvN-rmxUSKDNw47uAAeABU4JAAD2Yu0IF2uKQAfF0KnBfgMXP8gSCtGD+nAAPwPFxPea3SELazAMirXhFEClAzlWqeOBQAaEvx0pAwfBQAy4ODkynlSrVXjYJYdFyjNhwFBg5JpKw2DItFlsjl4IUrUXsCXi1LjCYmMxwWbcEAQAwABS4YDBOBl1kBYXcnh81rgKTtEUdfjI9hQXhcxQgEHayXGniyerNAUIDGqKCgWgBwKQoP1huN4YtjM93pcpnsxCi1gAjgkoCkMTjcvmOPgDGgugXywi4NEIMAtMGjJMw+bCBtkYnUcmQEbTd2M16fXB3AlK0WgqXy88nWRq7X6xc5o3m63tadzmmwfcuvIQMAYN991HdjGtNheJmvLwCQAyTn3stwP0B1Ac1gMhpHk8z33OZb3vR84BfPA319f1Ax-AYXl3FhgPAewvgvRgr1jTZgNmF4AHp8LhAALYAwTIydiJYIFJGYONyUgAxEywSiWEuE1plcNkplEGjoHgZcaxgYBjUHRjmK6MBuxcfcGStPxiVWKSIwAOnvOSnXlVl2TE41mOmVCujwFSTOUi1sHvFwpxYdUwVwgYnTlRYFR0g1wD0owDLAewjLgEyVLMwgLPHbM4mIMUNQw6NYwQ459EIkiKIomAqK5bhxKMXhyI7dk4jgCR2hAZimBEjkAHdT2IycyogfxoiCewIBQVFMFEBK9I4aAHkC1Z73ysFqy0JAyE8JA4y6nNiAZap-CYzqoHXeYeq6PrbjWydWiQAYVNEQSMFK3SmM8wzApk7tLy0a9GwAKToAANFSSEK5ixD24TRLcjKYC8nzTrgeyXFuh6nqQIqjFeld3o5T6PO+wy8FnEsLJXYLvWwQFsBSNgzojH6NL8BL5A5FKKKY4E4HsUbsE4srkngGBaqGtAvQEB4utxfL3mYZr-BJfoIVagmiOKCUxtm1imziBJeYlvqzNWLqyqolKgjgHqKKirDxoW+ydsKY0PiGLgIBY4gYAQf0YBGL5aCjZhvn51JoURrGMSxPBuTKBnYR2GpBTaYU4DVWKnVochKAwLougZfFGQ9FcYUthkEu+DQNDhOgASgLgFqo1niioFBaHBG5SZN8VCEIYAvCpYp2knWr+kc7AjctkYHKdARtI5Lpvi0YBokhHA+qxXhfk22pKgAMTCpBeFYb58P7wfYoyNqiN+VLaCgLLxTAbzgDQErRIY2HXgN+BLn3r5o7uAl5JsN5DZd7AzYARWLFJrfuW3GHt-poQexKF7UIfB+T+2WCKa2v4nRP3gEMF2IFXAsg-nOOY38CDEDtkgB26xZiALpAHVU0CHL6y5kHe8r8WRT3HBg3+TAkArVniHLSioODjk0jYLE3wYZHXgICW4AAiZgbhBHOiESImAYiXa3BwIg2Y7A9qyLrAuWYMcCRPy-CpRqXg6wDEUeOOA+FIScOsC4Hh6VYZwAEcIjoUjxG2NEXAGRcjP6KJXMotc-R1FpXeFonRej2DGO1MgdAcglAqQELsIIvcr5gCMZCbAOg0D4DBjAFSfotApFikAA).

I'm having some trouble with a React component props type definition. I have a component published on npm that currently takes a simple set of props, mostly booleans and strings, with one prop of type `RG` and some callback functions based around the `RG` type.

What I want to provide is the same component, but with an optional `boolean` prop that, when `true`, "flips" the component to use a new `RGIC` type instead of `RG`.  Assume this is the current `Props` interface:

```
interface Props {
  x: string;
  y: string;
  rg?: RG;
  func(rg: RG): void;
}
```

I would like to offer an overload of the component with this interface:

```
interface PropsIC {
  x: string;
  y: string;
  rg?: RGIC;
  func(rg: RGIC): void;
}
```

It's important that I retain backwards compatibility, so the new prop must be optional in the external API.

These are the types I've come up with:

```
type RGAny = RG | RGIC;

interface CommonProps {
  x: string;
  y: string;
  flag: boolean; // <-- this is the new prop
}
interface PropsStandard extends CommonProps {
  flag: false;
  query?: RG;
  func(q: RG): void;
}
interface PropsIC extends CommonProps {
  flag: true;
  query?: RGIC;
  func(q: RGIC): void;
}

type Props = (Omit<PropsStandard, 'flag'> & { flag?: boolean }) | (Omit<PropsIC, 'flag'> & { flag?: boolean });

type PropsImpl = PropsStandard | PropsIC;
```

And this is how I am using them:

> NOTE: I'm sure the types above could use some improvements, so feel free to comment on those, but the code block below is where the meat of my question lies.

```
// This is the exported component, the API surface
export function Component(props: Props) {
  if (props.flag) {
    return ComponentImpl({ ...props, flag: true } as PropsIC)
  }
  return ComponentImpl({ ...props, flag: false } as PropsStandard);
}

// This is the component's internal implementation with two overloads,
// one for RG props (flag is undefined or false) and one for RGIC props (flag === true).
function ComponentImpl(props: PropsStandard): JSX.Element;
function ComponentImpl(props: PropsIC): JSX.Element;
function ComponentImpl({ query, func, flag, x, y }: PropsImpl) {
  // On this next line, I want to declare RG or RGIC instead of RGAny,
  // based on the value of the flag prop (or whether props is PropsStandard or PropsIC).
  const [root, setRoot] = useState<RGAny>(query ?? { combinator: 'and', rules: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    func(root) // <-- TS error here because RGAny is not assignable to RG
  }, [root])

  return (<div>{flag ? 'True' : 'False'}</div>);
}
```

This is how the user might implement the component:

```
// The user's application component
const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<RG>({ combinator: 'and', rules: [] })
  const [queryIC, setQueryIC] = useState<RGIC>({ rules: [] })
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  return flag
    ? <Component x="test" y="test" query={queryIC} func={(q: RGIC) => console.log(q)} flag />
    : <Component x="test" y="test" query={query} func={(q: RG) => console.log(q)} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

I understand how to use custom type guards and the `in` operator (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67191040/765987) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350778/765987)), but I'm not sure how to apply them to the entire component function body without sort of duplicating the entire implementation.

Update: [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#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-j+fIABYsLQUC8E8KBgGA9jAGgTA6qejaQAYhowKIIZhgAgvByZTris7zsGNxhkM2YOjGMAAIrcikSYYrQabMDa5FNmUMChHw7a5k8uHRl21ZJqw+6FBR8BUYxczYMQ9GybMzEpvQjDMBCqKzNaFZtFW4ZiRJNhCeGt7ybGr6uiprHqUgxYfkggFkQIMDHqet5kX4dIQpc+qYUYcAvGiABEzBuMFcApCFYUwBF1Fojg1FzOwToJaKLhadOOK4RA7QAHT2BAXiigMKWunAP5Yp5NguD53AYVhgXRR0sWRc14WcoxCXUSlQpoGlYqYll5GhrlSAFUVJXsJV4yiMg6ByEoeUCLsQRdBCBFgBVWLYDoaD4CAWF5cUEBaCkgFAA) has updated typings based on @chazsolo's comment.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example

Comment: Is the TS playground example not sufficient?

Comment: it is ok, but if you minimize it a bit it will be much better

Comment: Have you considered typing your component instead of overloading? Something like `export function Component<T extends RG | RGIC = RG>(props: Props<T>) {` then using the generic `T` type for useState?

Comment: Yes, @chazsolo, I think that did it! I've updated the question with a link to an updated TS playground. Want to provide your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding an optional flag to your component, consider adding a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) similar to (not complete code):

```js
interface Props<T> & CommonProps {
  func(q: T): void;
  query: T;
}

function Component<T extends RG | RGIC = RG>(props: Props<T>) {
   // ...
}
```

`T extends RG | RGIC = RG` allows you to set the valid types that can be used (`RG` or `RGIC`) and defaults to `RG` in case a user doesn't pass one in. The correct type will then be inferred based on what was given to the component (*so things like the parameters in `func` don't need to be re-typed when used*).

Usage will look like:

```js
return flag
  ? <Component<RGIC> query={queryIC} func={(q) => console.log(q)} />
  : <Component<RG> query={query} func={(q) => console.log(q)} />;
```